# Namespaced constraint classes not found in routes after upgrade to Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've been using constraint classes in my `routes.rb` forever, like so:

```
get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: "oauth_accounts#create_or_update", constraints: Constraints::OmniauthCallbackConstraint.new
```

But after the upgrade to Rails 7, I got the following error when starting the application:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Constraints
```

The constraint classes are located in the `/lib/constraints/` folder and are namespaced by a module like so:

```
module Constraints
  class OmniauthCallbackConstraint
    def matches?(request)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

This particular file is called `/lib/constraints/omniauth_callback_constraint.rb`.

I thought the solution was to require this constraint file explicitly in `routes.rb` with `require 'omniauth_callback_constraint'`, but then I get the error:

```
Zeitwerk::NameError: expected file /lib/constraints/omniauth_callback_constraint.rb to define constant OmniauthCallbackConstraint, but didn't
```

I guess it seems it has trouble resolving the module name. I tried `require 'constraints/omniauth_callback_constraint'` too, but that results in the same error.

What is going on here? Do I always need the `require` in `routes.rb` from now when I use custom constraint classes? Or am I missing a configuration in my `application.rb`, for instance? And if I need the `require`, what is the correct syntax to include the namespaced constraint shown above?

Comment: this link may be can help you https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Arctodus and @widjajayd (thanks!), I quickly found out that the culprit was my old `autoload_paths` syntax in my `application.rb`. Instead of:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

this should now be

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/lib"
```

Background info can be found in [this paragraph](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#globs-in-config-autoload-paths) in the Zeitwerk documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with resolving module names and solved it by defining an empty module file

```rb
# /lib/constraints.rb
module Constraints
end
```

Comment: And what do your `require` statements look like then? I added this with several combinations of `require` statements, but still no luck...

Comment: I've had the files in auto loaded directories, so no manual requires needed that I can recall

Comment: Thanks! This lead me down the path of further investigating my autoload_paths and it turns out the my old syntax `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` is now invalid and should instead be `config.autoload_paths << "#{root}/lib"`. I don't even need the redundant `constraints.rb` file.

Comment: Hmmm, there is something missing here. The problem with wildcards is that you get additional stuff that is and WAS NOT even in classic meant to represent the `Object` namespace. Like `lib/assets`, to which the glob may expand to. So, to be clean, you don't want a wildcard. You want now and before just one item. Having said so, however, the wildcard expansion includes `lib` as well, so I don't quite see why it was not finding `Constraints`. Would it be possibel to restore the previous configuration, throw `Rails.autoloaders.log!`, and observe the traces wrt to `lib`?

Comment: Ah, I know what happened. The application has `lib/constraints` and that was returned by the glob. Nested root directories are supported, and the most nested one wins, so `lib/constraints` represented `Object` instead of `Constraints`. See what I mean before, the glob returns stuff that is not meant to be an autoload path. `classic` tolerated that as a side-effect of the implementation, but conceptually it was equally meaningless.